# How to use WebSocket in XAMPP server

Tags: php, websocket, xampp, localhost

How to enable `websocket` in `xampp` server? I use windows 10.
I want to build a chat based on `websocket` and but I can't connect to the websocket.

I found this article 
http://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/ but I don't understand how to connect php xampp to websocket.

Answer (score 5):

Uncomment `extension=php_sockets.dll` in `php.ini` file to enable websockets in php.

Comment: NOTE: some distributions of XAMPP may show this as `;extension=sockets` uncomment it if so :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

Go to the project folder and run the "`php php-socket.php`" command on the terminal and the websocket server will works.

Make sure that the php path is in the environment variables, or run with full php path: "`c:/xampp/full_path_to_php/php php-socket.php`".

After running the server, access `index.php` with your browser and the chat will works.

`php-socket.php` is a script that creates a websocket service, `class.chathandler.php` is a chat implementation on the server side and `index.php` is the client side.

Please, sorry for my English.

Comment: There is no `php-socket.php` file in the directory of `php.exe`. Not sure if this has changed in a later version of XAMPP. Using XAMPP 7.1.11, also tried latest, version 7.2.8.

Comment: @MagnusBull take a look at the examples on php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/de/sockets.examples.php

Answer (score 1):

I tried get to run the example too, with the same error. Following solution is working:

download the example code and copy to your htdocs folder.

open two tabs in your Browser. 1. run the php-socket.php and let it load. 2. run the index.php in the 2nd tab and the example will work.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and got it working because I already have a website running on XAMPP.

1. "`php-socket.php`" → Change line 3:

`define('PORT',"8090");`

to:

`define('PORT',"1337");`

2. "`php-socket.php`" → Change line 11:

`socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);`

to:

`socket_bind($socketResource, HOST_NAME, PORT);`

3. "`index.php`" → Change line 25:

`var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090/demo/php-socket.php");`

to:

`var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1337/demo/php-socket.php");`

4. Make a `.bat` file inside this `demo` folder:

```
@echo off
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -q "C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\php-socket.php"
```

5. Launch the `.bat` file, and keep the `cmd` open as this is the socket listener or server; as soon as you close it, the frontend will say "`Connection Closed`"

Comment: I'm running xampp local too, had no problem with the port. But I noticed that jquery was not loaded due to http instead of https on line 18 of index.php, and therefore it did not work.